# Can the "spoiler" extension be updated to cover "one boxed" links?

Tags: feature-request, design

When I try to use the "spoiler" format on a bare link, the result is just an exclamation point and the one boxed link.  See example [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52680/how-can-i-beat-the-true-final-boss-of-hitogata-happa/59531#59531).  Many YouTube videos contain spoilers in their title, as was the case here.  I realize I could put the link in text and force it out of one box (and I may do that in this case, pending the response to this question).  However, "one box" is a very attractive feature to question-askers, so I'm torn about which feature to use.  Especially when it comes to YouTube I'm much more inclined to visit the video when I can see the preview.

Comment: I think your idea of "Use a link instead of a one box for youtube" is the way to go.

Comment: This is kind of on a tangent, but I think spoiler tags in answers that *specifically hide the thing being asked about* is silly. If someone asked or clicked on the question, they obviously are looking for the stuff in the spoiler tag. Spoiler tags make some sense in question bodies, since then you protect people on the front page from getting an eyeful of something they didn't mean to, but it often seems actually detrimental when done in answers, since you're hiding the very thing people are specifically trying to read.

Comment: @Streno I totally agree, if its obvious the question is asking about something spoilerific, such as the true final boss, is there really a need to put answers in spoiler boxes?

Answer (score 4):

I support this feature-request for images, but I don't think having it on youtube will be a good idea.

Spoilers are revealed when the mouse hovers over them. Once you start playing the video, having it hidden or revealed based on where your mouse is is not a behavior I find reasonable, while on the other hand having it behave any other way is inconsistent with the rest of the spoiler box.

Comment: You make a good point about the video if playing within one box. What if one boxed YouTube links and similar just became a static image when inside spoilers - an image that links to the YouTube video when clicked. Then there would be no "video playing in hidden spoiler" scenario. Perhaps as other suggest I go too far to prevent spoilers though. ;)